# Lebesgue integral of two functions are equal, then the functions are equal a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $\psi,\phi$ be non negative measurable functions on the measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$. Such that,
$\psi \le \phi$. If,
$$\int_{X} \psi ~ d\mu = \int_{X} \phi ~ d\mu,$$
then $\psi = \phi$ a.e. on $X$.

Let, $g(x) = \phi(x) - \psi(x).$ Then  $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{+},$
$$ \mu(\{ x \in X: g(x) \ge \lambda \} ) \le \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{X}g(x) \le \frac{1}{\lambda}(\int_{X}\phi(x) ~ d\mu  ~  - ~ \int_{X}\psi(x) ~ d\mu  ) = 0.$$
Let, $V = \{x \in X: g(x) \ne 0 \}$ and $E_{n} = \{x \in X: g(x) \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$ for all  natural numbers $n \ge 1$. We have that,
$$V = \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}E_n $$
Then,
$$\mu(V) = \mu(\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}E_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n) = 0. $$

Therefore, $\psi = \phi$ a.e. on $X$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Result is false as stated.  You need $\phi$ to be integrable, not just measurable (i.e., you need the additional assumption that $\int_X\phi\,\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$).  Otherwise $\int_X\psi\,\mathrm{d}\mu-\int_X\phi\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ as $\infty-\infty$ need not be zero.

Comment: To add to @user10354138 's comment, after the assumption that $\phi$ is integrable, in the proof, shouldn't the last inequality be an equality?

Comment: @user10354138, assuming if we add that $\int_{X} \phi ~ d\mu < \infty$ assumption does the conclusion follow?

Comment: Yes, the proof works assuming $\phi$ is integrable.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad question but where does the first inequality $u(x \in X: g(x) \ge \lambda)  \le \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{X} g(x)$ come from ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds, it is called Chebyshev inequality. You can prove it using the definition of the leb. measure.

Comment: @Tobias Rieper: Thanks. I'm familiar with it but didn't see that it was being used. It's appreciated.